# c# WebBrowserControl navigate with cookie modified when requested

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control

I use httpclient to make authentification request on a website. I getback cookies for the result. So after I wanna display the website page on the webbrowserControl with cookies to keep authentification. So I did this.

```
var cookieString = "Cookie: PrestaShop-a30a9934ef476d11b6cc3c983616e364=uA6Y3X32j91I9iluFZIRX3c";
            wbbWebBrowser.Navigate(iUrl, "",null, cookieString);
```

Then via fiddler I inspect the resquest, and surprise, the cookie value (after "=") has changed....

```
Cookie: PrestaShop-a30a9934ef476d11b6cc3c983616e364=lIl7sfVtBj0qOmiMvtNBuQFrtZtwyyW
```

What's wrong please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. You have to clean cookies before the navigate. So I cleared by this way: (Make sur that you allow unsafe code in the properties project)

```
 private unsafe void ClearCookies()
    {
        int option = (int)3;
        int* optionPtr = &option;

        bool success = InternetSetOption(0, 81, new IntPtr(optionPtr), sizeof(int));
    }
```

thanks to this link :
[source](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.fr/2013/02/c-winforms-webbrowser-clear-all-cookies.html)